# How do you connect with an API in a functionally pure language?

Tags: api, functional-programming, referential-transparency

I am just interested to know how, in a purely functional language, you can connect with an API without introducing side effects?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*connect* with an API"? Are you talking about web APIs?

Comment: Functional libraries have APIs too, you know. It might help to be more specific about what *kind* of API you're talking about; presumably a non-pure one, so Don's answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purely functional languages, such as Haskell, support calling functions in foreign languages via ["foreign function interfaces"](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/ffi/ffi/ffi.html).

The question that arises is how to encode the types and behavior of the foreign language function into the purely functional language (e.g Haskell).

There are two cases to consider:

**Pure functions**

Functions in the foreign language without side effects can be directly embedded without semantic issue. An example is `sin :: CDouble -> CDouble` in C.

**Impure functions**

Impure functions have side effects. Often they modify state on the foreign language side. Such functions must be called in a dependency/sequential order, in order to sequence the side effects correctly.

To embed this in a purely functional language you can pass a token to and from the foreign function, representing the state. Each time you call the foreign function, you get back a new token, and the old one is thrown away. So

```
let state0 = initState
(v, state1) <- foreignFunction state0
(u, state2) <- foreignFunction state1
return (v,u)
```

the side effect is captured as a pure function that modifies (by association) the `state` variable. Passing these back and forth ensures safety.

To hide the plumbing of passing the state token around you can use a monad.

This approach is very common for interfacing with stateful foreign APIs from Haskell, for example. A product example: the [mersenne-twister binding.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mersenne-random/0.1/doc/html/System-Random-Mersenne.html), which uses the `MTGen` token as evidence that the library has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If the API is not also purely functional, then you cannot. The best thing to do is isolate the mutating effects, in order to easily recognize them in your code.

Comment: To the downvoter. You cannot make an impure function whose state you don't control pure. If you can maintain a state as in @DonStewart's example then you are okay, but many impure API's have state that you can't control.